# I updated core-js to 3.6.7 but found a bug. It said "Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded core-js to 3.6.7 of my existing react app. I found this bug: "Cannot find module 'react'. Although I updated the react app it didn't work.

Comment: It is a legit bug. I had this bug and fixed it myself. I posted it if in case it could help others. Why do you think it does not provide value to the community?

Comment: You forgot to install packages. Install, not _update_. That's user error, not a bug.

Comment: Agree with your point. It was a tricky situation that some developer could get into. In `package.json`, I had  `react` package installed however due to the version difference of core-js, it was not reflected properly.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had to update package-lock.json by running `npm install`. Problem solved :)

Comment: `npm run` *what*?

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. I mean `npm install`. Just run `npm install` it will update the package-lock.json file.